# Can I use express passport.js session google authentication with a next.js

Tags: express, next.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am tring to pick out a tech stack, so I wondered if I can use express passport.js session google authentication with a next.js?

Comment: Have you checked this offical example by nextjs https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-passport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next has his own build in server, that you can replace by your custom like `express`:

So answer is: **Yes** you can, but it has tradeoffs.

- some deployment options are not possible (eg next on vercel)
- serverless functions can't be used natively
- performance optimizations build in next and automatic static optimization are not possible

To get right decision you probably should read about [next deployment](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment). There are different support for custom servers depending from deployment option, if do you have your own vps/droplet then express always can be used with next.

There are great introduction to custom server in [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) and [discussion about pros and cons of express with next](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-server-rendered-react-app-next-express/).

Rest of mentioned stack: `passport.js session google authentication` are obviously possible to implement in express but you can also use them without express.

If you decide to not resign from build in server you can use it without express. Best place to start will be example mentioned by [@iAi Dev in comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-passport). It can be more tricky because you will have to skip all tutorials where express plugins are used and learn more about nuxt server but it can be good investment if you want to be focused on performance of flexibility of deployment or scaling.